# Why is "de" necessary in the phrase "c'est de moi dont il s'agit" ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-relatifs

It seems that the sentence perfectly makes sense without having the "de". To my mind, the idea of "de" is already suggested by the "dont", so I cannot see why you need to use "de" twice like "de moi de".

> Si vous entendez le titre « maître des cieux », c'est **de moi** dont il s'agit.

Par contre:

> Si vous entendez le titre « maître des cieux », c'est **moi** dont il s'agit.

Ou bien:

> Si vous entendez le titre « maître des cieux », c'est **de moi qu**'il s'agit.

Comment: It's just the way the verb "s'agir" ([wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/agir) 7) introduces its object. When used with an indirect object  "s'agir"  this object is introduced by *de*. Il s'agit de moi. C'est de moi qu'il s'agit/ C'est de moi dont il s'agit.  Verbs need different prepositions, *aller à*, *parler de*, *agir sur*, etc. to introduce their indirect objects.

Comment: As a non-native speaker who admittedly misuses (usually overuses) “en” and “dont," I’ll nevertheless hazard a guess in comment form that your redundancy radar (“redundar”?) is correct as well as your suggested correction, but personally, I’d prefer “C'est de moi **qu**'il s'agit” to avoid the double notion of “de.”

Comment: @Laure I think he knows *s'agir* requires the preposition *de*. But for example, you wouldn't say "C'est de le chat dont j'ai besoin," right? The *dont* stands alone. So why is it different for *s'agir* ?

Comment: @PapaPoule It's debatable and been debated for long. Both are found as [Grevisse points out](http://www.langue-fr.net/Dont-c-est-de-toi-qu-on-parle-dont-on-parle).

Comment: @Aerovistae Yes, this is exactly my point. In the case of "besoin", "dont" alone suffices. So I'd like to know why "s'agir" needs to take two "de"s.

Comment: @Aerovistae  Both are said : "c'est le chat dont j'ai besoin" "c'est **du** chat dont j'ai besoin" (not "de le"- but you know that)). As I said to Papa Poule it's debated... Although some people say it is not as good, the use of "de...dont" is quite common after "c'est.... " It's a question of preference,  usage has a lot to say in the way the language evolves and the way we speak. (Oh, no not that prescriptivism / descriptivism debate again!) ;-)

Comment: @régénérée Please read my comment to Papa Poule. Doesn't **need to**, it is just very common. And "C'est de toi /de lui dont j'ai besoin" is quite common (just google it...) and **not** considered as incorrect.

Comment: @Laure god damn it I wrote *de le*... Siiiigh. yes I most certainly knew that. slowly but surely.

Comment: If this is just a case of redundancy (& not one of grammaticality) then (in English, at least) not all redundancy is bad & to be avoided, especially when it helps to clarify one’s words (especially when speaking), such as the example in the link provided by @Laure with “du/le fond du mur dont" (where I think 2 DUs and a DONT DO add clarity) or when there's lots of words/ideas separating the “du” & the “dont" (to remind the listener that one is talking about "de" something). So maybe in French, also, whether something is “inutilement surabondant” or just “surabondant” is a judgment call..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"C'est de moi dont il s'agit" should not be used. It's a common mistake, as many people get mixed up between the two correct sentences "c'est moi dont" and "c'est de moi que".

Comment: L'emploi de dont a évolué : lire *http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/grammaire/emploi-pleonastique-dont-qui.php*, il est théoriquement incorrect pour les puristes *http://www.langue-fr.net/Dont-c-est-de-toi-qu-on-parle-dont-on-parle* mais pas pour le commun des francophones, cf. le commentaire de Laure : "C'est de toi/de lui dont j'ai besoin" est seulement une redondance de *de* (dont = de que) inaudible, mais pas une violation des règles. Il y a d'ailleurs des exemples cités qui sont peut-être correct à l'écrit, mais qui interpellent les oreilles contemporaines.Si doute : reformuler la phrase.

Comment: Je ne suis pas d'accord ! Pourquoi parler de "redondance" lorsqu'il s'agit clairement d'un pléonasme ? Ce que d'ailleurs confirme le lien cité. Pour moi, il y a donc bien violation des règles. Par ailleurs, je m'élève également contre le fait de parler "d'emploi qui a évolué" : c'est seulement une faute devenue de plus en plus courante... comme bien d'autres, d'ailleurs.

Comment: Je rejoins cFreed sur le dernier point. L'usage actuel, si je me fie à ce que je lis le plus souvent, consiste à écrire "je ne c'est pas se qui ces passer" au lieu de "je ne sais pas ce qui s'est passé". Est-on censé accepter aussi cette orthographe en arguant que la langue évolue, ou est-ce qu'on sort le stylo rouge ? Où place-t-on la barre entre "nouvel usage" et "faute répandue" ? Je soutiens qu'il faut un minimum d'exigence et que de ce fait "c'est de ça dont je parle" est à ranger dans les fautes. Ce n'est pas un ajout, ni une simplification, c'est une confusion qui n'apporte rien.