# "ce dont j'ai besoin, c'est d'un verre d'eau froide", what does the "d" in "d'un" signify and relate to?

Tags: grammaire, de

I came across this example in my Easy French Step by Step by Mcgraw Hill but I cannot fathom out why there is a "d'un".  What does it refer to?  Can this translate to english?  Are there any specific rules around this usage?

Comment: Similar question: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19184/why-is-de-necessary-in-the-phrase-cest-de-moi-dont-il-sagit?s=2|35.0348

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't see in that more than an idiomatic construction. In French the choice has been made to repeat the préposition or to include it in a partial ellipsis whereas in English the ellipsis is complete most of the time; this usage is found in other constructions.

> What I need is a glass of cold water.
>   Ce dont j'ai besoin, c'est d'un verre d'eau froide.

You wouldn't say in English "What I need, **it** is a glass of cold water."; that is not idiomatic English; however the addition of "it" (**c'**) is idiomatic French; the principle is the same for **de** (*or* **d'**), merely idiomatic usage, which involves, truly speaking, not much of a principle.

> What's reinforced concrete made with? Concrete and steel. With concrete and steel. 
>   Avec quoi est fait le béton armé? **Avec** du  béton et du fer.
>
> What are you in need of? Water! (*I am in need of* water!)
>   De quoi avez-vous besoin? **D'** eau! (*J'ai besoin* d'eau!)
>
> What have they been talking about? All sorts of things, but not that.
>   De quoi ont-ils parlé? **De** choses diverses mais pas **de** ça.
>
> What battle did they talk about? It's the battle of Waterloo. About the battle of Waterloo.
>  
>   De quelle bataille ont-ils parlé? C'est **de** la bataille de Waterloo. **De** la bataille de Waterloo.

Comment: C'est redondance grammaticale que de dire "ce dont j'ai besoin, c'est d'un verre d'eau". S'il y a "dont" il n'y a pas besoin de réécrire "de" avant l'objet du besoin, d'où "Ce dont j'ai besoin c'est un verre d'eau" ou "C'est d'un verre d'eau que j'ai besoin"

Comment: @Chewie Your reasoning is faultless; I also think that it would be better to say as you do.

Comment: @Chewie In your second sentence, however, it's not so simple and it seems that the logic of the relative pronoun makes necessary to have "dont" not "que"; the reasoning: in the "subordonnée relative", " j'ai besoin quoi?"  does not correspond to the expression "avoir besoin de"; therefore: "De quoi ai-je besoin?"; "dont" stands for "de quoi", roughly speaking.

Comment: @Chewie I thought I'd bring grits to your mill: "Ce dont j'ai besoin, et que je n'aurais pas tout de suite, c'est un verre d'eau."; indeed, now "d'un" would be very strange, and yet there is no difference in the grammar but for this "pause" if we might call so the intervening clause introduced by "et".

Comment: I see your point, but although it's used less often it's totally right to say "C'est d'un verre d'eau que j'ai besoin", check that essay from Rousseau entitled "C'est de l'homme que j'ai à parler": https://www.infolio.ch/livre/c%E2%80%99est-de-l%E2%80%99homme-que-j%E2%80%99ai-a-parler.htm

Comment: @Chewie The evidence! On print! Hard to refute! I shall however say this;  nowhere  in this world is there a systematic proofreading procedure applied before the publication of book: proofreading is a business of, albeit experienced individuals, no authority on the given language; that is the process through which language is regenerated, by willful tempering with it or by error. This is just one case and it dates from 2012, which makes the trend quite young, if there is a trend! I would wait for the a deeper analysis before concluding that an additional possibility has been introduced.

Comment: This 'one case' I am quoting is actually Jean-Jacques Rousseau, who counts among the most famous philosophers of French literature: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Jacques_Rousseau, and I trust him regarding the way he uses the language, and I believe he wouldn't have entitled his essay with a mistake in it (the date you saw 2012 is a re-edition, as said in the link I quoted it was published in 1755).

Comment: Of course the language regulates itself, but there are some innovations that sound right, and other that sound odd, and the example I pointed out sounds like a redundance. I am not saying it is a mistake, just that there is a more simple and elegant way to write it.

Comment: @Chewie You're right, those are the philosopher's words, from at least 1755, and that gives more credit to  this form we desagree about. I do understand that a genuine sense of taste is telling you that what you preconise would be more elegant. If you care for a more extensive exchange, feel free to continue in chat mode (personally I don't know how to pass to chat mode, I never used it).

Comment: @Chewie It's possibly the last comment that's allowed me and I won't be able to go on talking about this question so I propose you to consider the following; "C'est du français que j'ai à parler." et "C'est du français dont j'ai à parler.".

Comment: I understand this point of grammar is a little tricky, and one can easily get confused, but if you analyze it deeper: 'dont' already contains the article 'de' from its etymology (latin 'de unde'), that's why it's redundant to use bothe 'dont'+'de' in the same sentence. You can decompose the word 'dont' by replacing it by 'de quoi' ('Ce de quoi j'ai besoin'), which highlights the redundancy. Check the answer to that question https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19184/why-is-de-necessary-in-the-phrase-cest-de-moi-dont-il-sagit?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85075/discussion-between-user168676-and-chewie).